# Little boy or That little boy

Tags: articles, determiners

I recently saw this sentence: *Best wishes for little kid* which I think she should put a determiner or an article before *little kid*, E.g: *Best wishes for my little kid* or *Best wishes for that little kid*.

Is my thinking correct or the sentence is correct?

Comment: What is the relationship between the writer, the little kid, and the intended recipient of the expressed sentiment?  There are very few   situations in which ***that*** *little kid* would make sense.

Comment: I agree with you that in most cases 'that little kid' would not make sense much. In this case I just want to give a quick example of how to fix it.

Comment: @petwho- you still have not answered the questions I posed.  Context is important and will determine which determiner is most appropriate.

Comment: @Jim She (the one who wrote this sentence) was giving wishes to her cousin (maybe on his birthday but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you certainly need a determiner of some sort, and probably a definite one at that.

- Best wishes for the little kid.
- Best wishes for that little kid.
- Best wishes for my little kid.
- Best wishes for your little kid.
- Best wishes for our little kid.

I don't think indefinite determiners make as much sense there:

- Best wishes for a little kid.
- Best wishes for some little kid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a determiner is necessary in   this case. Besides, best wishes for little **kids** may be better just in this sentence.